# finding a formula for this summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, algorithms, computational-complexity

$$\sum_{i=0}^{(n/2) - 1}{n-2i \choose 2}$$

Where $n$ is an even natural number.
For example : If **n=8** then I want the summation for this as a formula:

$${8 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 2}+....+{2 \choose 2}$$

I need a formula for this equation to calculate complexity for an algorithm that does a Complete Search: Using recursive backtracking and trying all possible pairings on 2D grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=2k$ for natural number $k$. Then the summation equals :

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{2k-2i\choose 2}$$ $$=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{(2k-2i)!}{2!(2k-2i-2)!}}$$ $$=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{2(k-i)^2}-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{(k-i)}$$
$$
=2\sum_{i=1}^{k}{i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}{i}$$

I hope you can take it over from here.

Comment: thanks a lot , i got it now and i can complete it myself , but can you give me more details about how did you got into the 3rd step from the second one ?
and also why in the summation it's (k-1) not only (k)?

Comment: okay i got now , thanks for help